# Django avoids creating PointField in the database when I run python manage.py syncdb

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, postgis

I'm using Django 1.2.3, PostGIS 1.5.2.

For some reason when I run

> python manage.py syncdb

it's creating all the other fields in the database from my models but avoids creating a field I named point that supposed to be a PointField.

In my model.py files I have imported:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```

and commented:

```
#from django.db import models
```

my model looks something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    point = models.PointField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

Also when is creating the admin side I get the errors below:

```
Failed to install index for reports.MyModel model: permission denied for relation spatial_ref_sys
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT SRID         FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE SRID = new_srid"
PL/pgSQL function "addgeometrycolumn" line 74 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','',$1,$2,$3,$4,$5)"
PL/pgSQL function "addgeometrycolumn" line 4 at SQL statement
```

In my setting.py I've added:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
```

and

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
   'django.contrib.gis',
...
```

Any ides why I'm heaving this issues? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that the PostgreSQL user role django was using had insufficient rights.

What happened when I enabled my database with the PostGIS it created  a couple of tables "geometry_columns" and "spatial_ref_sys" using a different user role. So again when Django was trying to access those two tables it chocked because it didn't have enough rights.

It was that simple, whew :)

Comment: Did you change the role of the django user to Superuser?

Comment: I just got the same error and fixed it by changing the owner of the two tables in question with SQL like this: `ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO newuser` executed as a superuser.

Comment: The only way to get access to the `spatial_ref_sys` column was by using the superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to let you know that I was getting this error on Django 1.4.3, Postgres 9.1 and PostGIS 2.
It worked after I downloaded and used the latest Django dev (1.6 alpha).
There was no need for the Postgres user to be superuser. Apparently the support of PostGIS 2 is added in Django 1.5