# GeoDjango: syncdb failing to create PointField

Tags: django, postgis, postgres.app

I am using Django 1.2 and the latest version of [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) on MacOS 10.7. When I run `manage.py syncdb` to create a database with a PointField in it, I get the following error:

```
Installing index for stores.Store model
Failed to install index for stores.Store model: operator class "gist_geometry_ops" does not exist for access method "gist"
```

This are the Postgres commands that I am using beforehand to create a spatial database (after having [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737982/django-avoids-creating-pointfield-in-the-database-when-i-run-python-manage-py-sy) previously) - none of them produce any errors, which suggests that PostGIS is set up okay:

```
$ psql -d stores -U storeadmin
# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
# ALTER TABLE geometry_columns OWNER TO storeadmin;
# ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO storeadmin;
```

Having done a bit of Googling, I'm wondering if perhaps Postgres.app comes with a version of PostGIS that is incompatible with Django 1.2? Should I upgrade to a newer Django? Or should I downgrade to an older PostGIS, and if so, how?

UPDATE: [This thread](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16455) suggests that even Django 1.4 isn't compatible with PostGIS 2. Can I persuade Postgres.app to use an older version? Or should I give up on Postgres.app altogether?

Comment: Can't you just load the PostGIS 1.x compatibility scripts that come with PostGIS 2.0?

Comment: Also since Django 1.5 (currently in beta) GeoDjango supports PostGIS 2.0+. In case you are interested and you want to give it a try we (in BitNami) recently released an installer[http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack] that includes Python, Django 1.5 and PostgreSQL with PostGIS 2.0.1. It is selft-contained and will not interfere with anything else in your system.

Answer (score 0):

GeoDjango 1.5 has been released with support for PostGIS 2.0.  At this point your best option is to upgrade.